# Remove everything from a string except a date with a certain pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm trying to remove everything but a date (dd-mm-yyyy) from a string that I fetch from the database in a foreach.

I could've just removed all text ([A-Z][a-z] etc), but there's numbers in between the text aswell.

```
$strings = [
    'Originele startdatum ',
    'Op verzoek van klant de ingangsdatum gelijkgetrokken met alle andere abonnementen zodat er maar 1 factuur wordt verstuurd.'
];

$result[] = [
    'AboOpmerking' => str_replace($strings, '', $row['AboOpmerking']),
];
```

The untouched strings look like this:

Example 1:

> Originele startdatum 3-10-2017

Example 2:

> Originele startdatum 1-1-2014 Op verzoek van klant de ingangsdatum
>   gelijkgetrokken met alle andere abonnementen zodat er maar 1 factuur
>   wordt verstuurd.

I've found this regex, but I don't know how to use it, because it gives me an empty array when I print `$matches`

```
^([0]?[1-9]|[1|2][0-9]|[3][0|1])[./-]([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2])[./-]([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$
```

Comment: Are you trying to match or trying to remove? What should be exact output?

Comment: This is very complex regex. Would this work `$date = preg_replace("([^0-9-])", "", $stringWithDate);`

Comment: @DanMiller No because as I stated in my question there can be numbers within the text after the date, and this seems to match all numbers and `-`

Comment: Are you trying to do this `(?<!\S)\d+-\d+-\d{4}(?!\S)` ? https://regex101.com/r/XyECCO/1

Comment: @revo Thanks for that. As of now the date won't be of a different format, so the accepted answer is fine for me. But I'll save this one aswell, thanks.

Comment: You are not validating by any means I think. You are just trying to match. So you don't need a monster regex to match dates. You can be more specific though, [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570670/remove-everything-from-a-string-except-a-date-with-a-certain-pattern?noredirect=1#comment86150128_49570766) wasn't forced to comment about regex I provided but to put him aside you can change above regex a little `(?<!\d)\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}(?!\d)`. You'd better use this over yours.

Comment: Thanks, I'll reconsider what I'm going to use later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace `^` (that matches the *start* of string location) and `$`  (that matches the *end* of string location) with `\b` (word boundaries) to match the date substrings as whole words, and use `preg_match` (to extract only the first match) or `preg_match_all` (if there are more than one):

```
preg_match('~\b(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([./-])(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\1(?:[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})\b~', $s, $matches);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aDY13o/1)

An alternative to word boundaries can be `(?<!\d)` and `(?!\d)` lookarounds (that are helpful if the dates can be glued to letters or appear in between underscores):

```
preg_match('~(?<!\d)(?:0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([./-])(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\1(?:[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})(?!\d)~', $s, $matches);
```

Comment: Both look good, I think the second one will be more fail-proof, so I'm going with that one. What does the `~` do exactly?

Comment: @KeesSonnema These are [regex delimiters](http://php.net/manual/pl/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). They separate parts of the regex: 1) action, 2) pattern and 3) flags/options.

Comment: I know, was about to.

Comment: @KeesSonnema BTW, [revo suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570670/remove-everything-from-a-string-except-a-date-with-a-certain-pattern/49570766?noredirect=1#comment86149387_49570670) a simpler regex that may extract substrings that are similar to dates. `(?<!\S)\d+-\d+-\d{4}(?!\S)` matches 1+ digits, `-`, 1+ digits, `-` and 4 digits when enclosed with whitespace (so, no matches when inside punctuation or letters), and may match `122432345-42343453254564-2456` strings.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, there is an alternative  where you could match a date like format `\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}` and create a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and perhaps specify the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to verify it is a valid date.

To replace only the first date, you might use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and specify 1 as the fourth parameter to do only 1 replacement.

```
$strings = [
    'Originele startdatum 3-10-2017',
    'Originele startdatum 3-10-2017 3-10-2018 ',
    'Originele startdatum 1-1-2014 Op verzoek van klant de ingangsdatum gelijkgetrokken met alle andere abonnementen zodat er maar 1 factuur wordt verstuurd.'
];

$pattern = '/\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}/';
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches) === 1 && false !== DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $matches[0])) {
        echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $string, 1) . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll reconsider what I'm going to use later.